# Ordering issue with Instantiation of Spring XML and Java Configuration Beans Related to Properties

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, javabeans

I have an ordering problem. My @Bean runs after my XML Bean. I need this reversed, because my @Bean establishes properties the XML Bean needs.  It appears @ImportResource annotations are processed before @Configuration, @Bean annotations are processed.

I have a configuration class bootstrapped by another class annotated with @ContextConfiguration.  The first is annotated as such:

- @Configuration
- @Import(PropertyConfiguration.class)
- @ImportResource(Consts.XML_BASED_CONFIG_FILE)

PropertyConfiguration.class includes a @bean definition that uses PropertySource ( not the annotation )  to pull in properties for use by the XML bean defined in Consts.XML_BASED_CONFIG_FILE.

The @ImportResource is a routine reference to an existing XML based bean def file so that both java and xml beans interoperate.

Everything runs great except for this ordering issue.

I’ve tried bringing in the properties using @ProperySource – best I can tell the annotation does not support running a custom bean as the property source is a JDBC database. I’ve established the @PropertySource runs before @ImportResource so this would have resolved the ordering. 
I’ve tried @Lazy(false) on my @Bean method – doesn’t help.

The next thing will be bootstrapping @configuration from my XML file – however, I’m thinking this will not matter.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm... I tried bootstrapping XML first but does not help.

Answer (score 0):

`@ImportResource` annotations are indeed processed before `@Configuration`, `@Bean` annotations are processed. I did not find a way to reverse this order. As the imported resource is an XML file based bean definition referencing Spring properties, the properties are not yet set  before the bean is created and results in an error.  This implies, you cannot implement `@Configuration`, `@Beans` along side XML Beans when you set properties within the `@Bean` method and expect those properties to be set before being referenced by the XML bean.

In my case, the `@Bean` was establishing properties from a JDBC source.

To get around this, I had to convert each XML Bean referencing  properties to `@Beans`.

Hope this helps